# How do I write to the chrome console using dart console object?

Tags: angular-dart

The dart console has a private constructor and is set to internal only. I'm looking for more functionality than just a standard print. Like the ability to print an object or JSON.

Comment: I'm not really into angular-dart but what's wrong with the standard `print` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DDC (don't know about dart2js)

you can use the console debug function, you should be able to inspect inside your object

```
window.console.debug(obj);
```